# How to print multi-level list in Spring

Tags: spring, list, jstl

I want to print a multi-level list like this using jslt in Spring, how to code the controller and jsp?

- News-cat-1

  - News item1
  - News item2
  - News item3
- News-cat-2

  - News item1
  - News item2
  - News item3
- News-cat-3

  - News item1
  - News item2
  - News item3

Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loadHomePage(ModelMap map) {

    List<NewsCategory> cat = newsService.getNewsCat();

    for(NewsCategory c : cat){
          List<News> list = newsService.getByCat(c.getId());

          map.put("list-" + c.getId(), list); // is this right?
    }

    map.put("newscat", cat);

    // And how to print these in the jsp page?

    return "index";
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${myMap}"> 
 List name: <c:out value="${entry.key}"/>
  <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="cat" varStatus="rowStatus">
                <c:forEach items="${cat.itemList}" var="item" varStatus="rowCount">
                    <div>...<c:out value="${item.description}"/></div>
                </c:forEach>
        </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: In my code, ModelMap contains many list of news with name list-1, list-3, list-4..... these are dynamic names, not only "${list-1}". Because I dont know value returned by c.getID() so I dont know the attribute name to get the value in jsp. Sorry for my English.